# configure CMake to specify Public Include Directories

Tags: visual-studio, cmake

I am trying to add a CMake project into an existing Visual Studio (2022) solution. Ex. my main app is a VS C++ Project and I want to link a CMake library.

Although I can compile the library, the library doesn't export or expose the header folders. There is a configuration for that in the project settings, called "Public Include Directories".

My question is how should I configre the CMakeLists to expose the headers?

```
# This is what I have so far
add_library(myLib STATIC myLib.cpp myLib.h)
target_include_directories(myLib PUBLIC "${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}")
# maybe use set_target_properties()?
# maybe use install()?
```